# Writing SQL INSERT which retrieves its data from two separate related rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am writing a SQL script that is to insert a new record using data from two rows that are under the same AccountID.

My table looks like the following:

```
AccountID | ActivityId | DisplayDetails | TransactionDate    | EnvironmentId
============================================================================
1              7         Display1        2015-02-02 00:00:00.000    1
1              8         DisplayThis1    2018-02-02 00:00:00.000    1
1              7         Display2        1999-02-02 00:00:00.000    2
1              8         DisplayThis2    2000-02-02 00:00:00.000    2
```

My fix is to find find each 7,8 combination and insert a new row with ActivityId 78 that gets the DisplayDetails from ActivityId 7 and TransactionDate from ActivityId 8.

My queries looks like the following:

```
SELECT * 
INTO #ActivityEight
FROM Account A
WHERE A.ActivityId = 8


INSERT INTO #Account (AccountId, ActivityId, DisplayDetails, TransactionDate)
SELECT VL.AccountId, 78, S.DisplayDetails, VL.TransactionDate
FROM #temp2 VL WITH(NOLOCK)
JOIN #ActivityEight S
    ON VL.AccountId = S.AccountId
WHERE VL.ActivityId = 7
```

However when I run SELECT * FROM Account I get a 78 row for each 7 and 8 row, when I should only get 1 78 row per 7 and 8 combination.

```
AccountID | ActivityId | DisplayDetails | TransactionDate     | EnvironmentId
=============================================================================
   1            7        Display1        2015-02-02 00:00:00.000    1
   1            8        DisplayThis1    2018-02-02 00:00:00.000    1
   1            7        Display2        1999-02-02 00:00:00.000    2
   1            8        DisplayThis2    2000-02-02 00:00:00.000    2
   1           78        DisplayThis1    2015-02-02 00:00:00.000    NULL
   1           78        DisplayThis2    2015-02-02 00:00:00.000    NULL
   1           78        DisplayThis1    1999-02-02 00:00:00.000    NULL
   1           78        DisplayThis2    1999-02-02 00:00:00.000    NULL
```

I believe I can utilize the EnvironmentId to achieve the desired functionality, but I'm not sure how.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Where does `#temp2` come into this? What output do you want?

Comment: And why do you need to use the nolock hint? Especially with a local temp table?

Comment: Apologies, #temp2 should have been #Activity. 

NOLOCK hint is there from habit, it's not meant to be there.

Comment: As in your other question, each pair is conveniently identified by `EnvironmentId`. Is this really the case in all the source data?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you

```
INSERT INTO #Account (AccountId, ActivityId, DisplayDetails, TransactionDate)
SELECT VL.AccountId, 78, S.DisplayDetails, VL.TransactionDate
FROM Account VL WITH(NOLOCK)
JOIN Account S ON VL.AccountId = S.AccountId and VL.EnvironmentId = S.EnvironmentId
WHERE VL.ActivityId = 7 and S.ActivityId = 8
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work @Ravi. If I run the SELECT without the INSERT INTO above it, I don't get any results. Do you have another suggestion?

Comment: what is EnvironmentId for?