# SQL data fix INSERT that retrieves data from several rows that have the same ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is a snippet of the CreditCard table:

```
CreditCardID | ActivityId | CardDetails | TransactionDateTime    | TradingId
============================================================================
1              5         CardDetails1     2015-02-02 00:00:00.000    1
1              6         CardsDetails1    2016-02-02 00:00:00.000    1
1              5         CardDetails2     1999-02-02 00:00:00.000    2
1              6         CardsDetails2    2000-02-02 00:00:00.000    2
1              6         CardsDetails22   2000-02-03 00:00:00.000    2
```

My fix is to find find each 5,6 combination and insert a new row with ActivityId 66 that gets the CardDetails from ActivityId 5 and TransactionDateTime from ActivityId 6.

My queries looks like the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T.CreditCardID
INTO #temp
FROM CreditCard T WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE ActivityId IN (5, 6)
GROUP BY T.CreditCardID
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN T.ActivityId = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN T.ActivityId = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND

SELECT B.* 
INTO #CreditCardTemp
FROM #temp A 
JOIN CreditCard B 
    ON A.CreditCardID = B.CreditCardID

INSERT INTO CreditCard (CreditCardID, ActivityId, CardDetails, TransactionDateTime, TradingId)
SELECT A.CreditCardID, 66, B.CardDetails, A.TransactionDateTime, B.TradingId
FROM #CreditCardTemp A
JOIN #CreditCardTemp B 
    ON A.CreditCardID = B.CreditCardID 
    AND A.TradingId = B.TradingId
WHERE A.ActivityId = 5
AND B.ActivityId = 6
```

However when I run SELECT * FROM CreditCard I get a 66 row for each 6 row, when I should only get 1 66 row per 5 and 6 combination (irrespective of how many ActivityId 6 it has).

Eg. If I have one ActivityId 5 and two ActivityId 6 under the same CreditCardID and TradingId, I should only get one new 66 row, whereas here I am getting two extra 66 rows.

I believe I need to modify my ActivityId 6 join to only retrieve one ActivityId 6 record and the one record retrieved is the earliest of the Activity Id 6's. However I need writing this JOIN.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You should resolve your old question first. That might help you fix this one since it seems identical. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51889051/writing-sql-insert-which-retrieves-its-data-from-two-separate-related-rows

Comment: It's not identical, It's using a similar table structure but the question is entirely different @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: Good day, instead of stories about how the table looks like, please provide queries to create the table and to insert some sample rows, and post the requested result according to the sample data. Let us use that time to help 2 more people and focus on the issue instead of working on what you should provide us to reproduce the issue ;-) Thanks

Comment: Regardless of how different it is or isn't, you're more likely to help if we can see that you are interested in finishing off your older questions. (i.e. adding detail when requested)

Answer (score 0):

I think your sample dataset is probably incomplete but this is how I would do it.

I am taking advantage of patterns in your data, which may not exist consistently in your real data

In your example, each pair is conveniently grouped by a `TradingID` value

```
SELECT 
CreditCardId,
66 As ActivitytId,
TradingID, 
MAX(CASE WHEN ActivityId = 5 THEN CardDetails ELSE NULL END) AS CardDetails,
MAX(CASE WHEN ActivityId = 6 THEN TransactionDateTime ELSE NULL END) AS TransactionDateTime
FROM CreditCard 
WHERE ActivityId IN (5,6)
GROUP BY TradingID, CreditCardId
HAVING MIN(ActivityId) = 5 AND MAX(ActivityId) = 6
```

Comment: PS, you can apply a similar idea to your other question since groups of data are identified by `EnvironmentId`

Comment: Note how similar @D-Shih answer is to your third question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51922362/sql-script-that-inserts-a-new-row-using-from-multiple-related-rows-under-the-sam